# Ofbiz framework repeatedly prompts for login credentials

Tags: amazon-ec2, ofbiz, amazon-vpc

I am using **ofbiz** for an e-commerce site and I have recently migrated from **EC2 type** amazon servers to **VPC type** servers provided by Amazon.

After migrating I often see ofbiz asking for **login credentials** again and again before performing any task. In other words, I have to provide my credentials again and again to accomplish any single task.

Google couldn't help me with this neither the ofbiz forums, any hint if not the exact solution would also help.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of problem often requires some research and testing, but I'd start with looking at session related issues like cookies (for plain HTTP) and HTTPS sessions, and also that the jsessionid is included in the URL when switching between HTTP and HTTPS.

It may be that something in the network is different between the plain EC2 and the private cloud and that is causing issues with maintaining the session. I don't know a lot about VPC on AWS, so can't comment on more detailed things to look into there.

Comment: thank you for answering, i will check for the jsessionid and see if it works.